# Adding second animation on same object removes css properties

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to create a progress bar using a `div` and `border-bottom` property.

I've two classes:

`anim-start`: This makes the progress bar go from 0 to 70%
`anim-end`: This makes the progress bar go to 100%, and them remove the border

I'm using the property `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so that the css properties stay.

The problem is that when I apply the second class, it would remove the properties of earlier class, and therefore the progress bar would just vanish.

Please see the fiddle below:

```js
  var progress_bar = document.querySelector(".progress")
  progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-start";

  setTimeout(function() {
    progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-end";
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.progress.anim-start {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-start-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-start-anim {
  0% {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.progress.anim-end {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-end-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-end-anim {
  99% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have the second animation start off from where the first one ends:

```js
  var progress_bar = document.querySelector(".progress")
  progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-start";

  setTimeout(function() {
    progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-end";
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.progress.anim-start {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-start-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-start-anim {
  0% {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.progress.anim-end {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-end-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-end-anim {
  0% {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    width: 70%;
  }
  99% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
```

---

the reason why your version isn't working is that your second animation is being overridden by the first, and you're missing `border-bottom:` property in the second.

```js
  var progress_bar = document.querySelector(".progress")
  progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-start";

  setTimeout(function() {
    progress_bar.className = progress_bar.className + " anim-end";
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.progress.anim-start {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-start-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-start-anim {
  0% {
border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
width: 70%;
  }
}

.progress.anim-end {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: progress-end-anim;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-end-anim {
  0% {
border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
   /* */
  }
  99% {
width: 100%
  }
  100% {
border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I can do this, but this has a very small (not much noticeable) blink when it changes from first to second animation. My question is that why is my method not working?

Comment: @KartikAnand your second animation doesn't start from 0%

Comment: But I thought that isn't needed. Shouldn't it start from previous css values and now continue till 100% ?

Comment: @KartikAnand the second animation overrides the first one, so when the second one is placed it flushes previous width value

Comment: My doubt is: I'm using `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so the width value after first animation should stick. Secondly, I'm changing width to 100% in second animation, which runs for 2 seconds, so shouldn't the progress bar go till 100% and then vanish?

Comment: the problem is that in the second animation you don't define the border

Comment: I get that I'm not defining the border, because the border is already there from the previous animation.

Comment: if the animation gets overridden it's not there anymore, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/Lx45y5cz/) an example with just one animation; `animation-fill-mode: forwards` will not persist on the element if the animation is removed

Comment: Oh That's why!. So one element cannot have multiple animations I guess, which makes sense!